# Excel Add In for Quality Center won't run in 64 bit excel - is there a workaround?

Tags: quality-center, excel

Our company recently upgraded everyone to Office 2010, the 64 bit version. This broke the functionality of the HP Excel ADD IN for Quality Center that I had been using. I prefer to write my test cases in Excel and then export them to Quality Center.

Has anyone found a workaround? HP does not currently have a solution.

Edit:
As per the answer, I cannot install 32-bit MS Office as am using Office comp. Is there any other workaround.

Comment: We had a number of things break when upgrading to Office 2010 on our webapps. Granted they're homebrew, not HP, but as yet there's no workarounds we've found. I suspect it is a fundamental change in the API which can only be fixed by changing how the tool itself interacts with Excel. I know this isn't very encouraging :-(

Comment: Thanks corsiKa. Not encouraging, but it is informative. We've also noticed that the Document Generator feature was broken as well, since it cannot interface with 64 bit version of Word.

Answer (score 2):

Our shop uses ALM 11.00 (new version of QC) but on the add-in page it specifically says the following Excel versions are supported:

Versions supported: Microsoft Excel 2007 and 2010 (32 bit) with HP ALM 11.00.

I would uninstall office 2010 and restall it as a 32 bit version.  THe 32 bit version works on a 64 bit machine and I'm able to use the excel plugin without issue.